# why linewidth was not set?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm making bouncting ball program.
I want to draw wall and set wall's linewidth.
For setting wall's linewidth, I added "ctx.linewidth=30;" that is 
written line 3 in my code.
But nothing happened. 
I was so wonder at linewidth that I changed ctx.linewidth=50;
still nothing happened.
how to set wall's linewidth?

```
function init() {
  ctx=document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.linewidth=30;
  ctx.fillStyle="rgb(200,0,50)";
  moveball();
  setInterval(moveball, 700);
}
function moveball() {
  ctx.clearRect(boxx,boxy,boxwidth,boxheight);
  moveandcheck();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ballx,bally,ballrad,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeRect(boxx,boxy,boxwidth,boxheight);
  document.getElementById('px').value=ballx;
  document.getElementById('py').value=bally;

}
```

Comment: Its `ctx.lineWidth` not `ctx.linewidth`  with a capital W

Answer (score 1):

The Function on line 3 of your's is supposed to be `ctx.lineWidth` and not `ctx.linewidth`.

With Capital W.

Comment: Indeed, for reference: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-line-width/